Is the expected length of a random VRP known?
I have some regular area (e.g. a rectangle or a square), and I have $N$ random points there. Further, I have $k$ agents to visit the random points. The aim is to minimise total costs. Is there any result on the expected cost of the solution?
To be precise, the points are all random, independent and uniform. For a given set of points, the question is: “how to create $k$ paths so that all points are visited and minimising the total length?”. For $k=1$, it is TSP, and despite being NP-hard, there are some results on the expected value of the optimal solution. My question is whether this exists for $k \geq 2$.
I am thinking something like this result but for VRP instead of TSP. Even with the agents, I would be satisfied. Thanks in advance!

Can you give some more context? Are your $N$ points uniformly distributed on the rectangle? What about the agents? What does it mean for an agent to "visit" a point?

Yes, sorry for the lack of clarity. The points are all random, independent and uniform. For a given set of points, the question is “how to create k paths so that all points are visited, and minimising the total length?”. For k=1 it is TSP and, despite being np hard, there are some results on the expected value of the optimal solution. My question is whether this exists for k>=2.

I'd suggest you edit your question with all these details!
